# How to unit test a date returned in particular format

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I want to write a unit test such that it returns date in a particular format. I pass "2020-02-25" and the function returns "25-Feb-2020".

**file.js**

```
module.exports = { 
   convertDate
};
function convertDate (date) {
  console.log(date);
    let  date1 = new Date(date);
    console.log(date1);
    let formattedDate = date1.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
    day: 'numeric', month: 'short', year: 'numeric'
    }).replace(/ /g, '-');
    console.log( formattedDate);
    return formattedDate;
}
```

**file.spec.js**

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const filejs = require('./file.js');

     it.only('should return the date in 25-Feb-2020 format when I pass date in 2020-02-25' ,function () {
       let fdate = filejs.convertDate("2020-02-25");
       expect(fdate).to.equal('25-Feb-2020');

     })
```

When I run the test, test fails

AssertionError: expected 'Feb-25,-2020' to equal '25-Feb-2020'

Comment: Let me know if my question is not clear

Comment: The problem here is the fact that `Feb 25, 2020` cannot be converted to `25-Feb-2020` by simply replacing the white space with a dash. Your unit test is fine, but you'll need to change the implementation of `convertDate`. Also keep in mind that dates in the "year-month-day" format [assume a time zone of UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Differences_in_assumed_time_zone) so the output date may not match the input date unless you add `timeZone: 'UTC'` to your formatting options.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the unit test is ok, but the problem is that your function returns 'Feb-25,-2020'.